# How to change Current theme to Window classic Theme in Window7 at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7

I am working with ASP.net and C# . Now, I have developed a web application. I want to change the current theme to windows classic theme in Window7(IE8) because my design is disordered when other theme used. Could I change theme at run time? Could I do this  *OnPreInit() Event*. Please help me .

With regards,

Comment: Check [this](http://davidrobertmattson.com/wordpress/?p=48) out.

Comment: Based on the other question too, I think its time to pick up a book on ASP.Net & CSS.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson ... thanks a lot . And which book I should read. If you have any link , please give me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix your CSS rather than change the entire windows theme to make it work...

Plus you cant launch a Process on the client from an ASP.Net, never the less here is the answer for non-web applications:

Ref: http://davidrobertmattson.com/wordpress/?p=48

```
//Sets the current theme
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.FileName = “rundll32.exe”;
string startuppath = Application.StartupPath.ToString();
string Arguments = “Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /File:\”C:\\Windows\\Resources\\Themes\\Windows Classic.Theme\”";
startInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
try
{
// Start the process with the info we specified.
// Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
exeProcess.WaitForInputIdle();

IntPtr p = exeProcess.MainWindowHandle;
ShowWindow(p, 1);
SendKeys.SendWait(“{enter}”);
}
}
catch
{
// Log error.
}
```

Comment: Yeah you cant do it with a Web Application - its running on a Server - not on the client PC. This is why I said to get an ASP.Net book as well as the CSS one. Let me know if anything is unclear?

Comment: yes, I am very clear your answer. I have tried a lot to change my CSS. But I can't. If you have any link which is suitable for me, please give me.

Comment: why cant you change the CSS, thats how you can fix your problem. Here is the gold tip you've been wanting. Download Firefox, install Firebug plugin, open FireBug in FF and goto your webpage then click the FireBug touchlight button and drag it over the HTML element that has the styling problem and adjust the CSS properties on-the-fly until the style is correct, then apply those changes to the CSS (on-the-fly) to your CSS file and bingo problem solved.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have changed  CSS to adjust my design. Now, it is OK.

Comment: great to hear, hope it looks shmick:)